Can guacamole change the viewport to a single monitor on a multimonitor system?
Can guacamole change the viewport to a single monitor on a multimonitor system?
Is this a feature VNC clients possess in general?
I have VNC server running on a multimonitor system, ie a laptop with its built-in 1366x768 screen and a 1920x1080 monitor.
When I check the VNC server logs it indicates it shows that a 3286x1080 virtual  screen has been created. Regardless of how I set the geometry to be 3286x1080+1366+0, or leave it to the defaults this is what guacamole displays.

I have tried
x11vnc -geometry 3286x1080+1366+0 -noxdamage -ncache_cr -wait 5 -defer 5 -display :5
and
x11vnc  -noxdamage -ncache_cr -wait 5 -defer 5 -display :5
I didn't fare much better with x0tigervncserver either.
This part of the log when x11vnc starts up.
29/08/2024 13:40:11 
29/08/2024 13:40:11 X FBPM extension not supported.
29/08/2024 13:40:11 X display is capable of DPMS.
29/08/2024 13:40:11 --------------------------------------------------------
29/08/2024 13:40:11 
29/08/2024 13:40:11 Default visual ID: 0x21
29/08/2024 13:40:11 Read initial data from X display into framebuffer.
29/08/2024 13:40:11 initialize_screen: fb_depth/fb_bpp/fb_Bpl 24/32/13144
29/08/2024 13:40:11 WARNING: Width (3286) is not a multiple of 4. VncViewer has problems with that.
29/08/2024 13:40:11 
29/08/2024 13:40:11 X display :5 is 32bpp depth=24 true color
29/08/2024 13:40:11 
29/08/2024 13:40:11 Autoprobing TCP port 
29/08/2024 13:40:11 Autoprobing selected TCP port 5900
29/08/2024 13:40:11 Autoprobing TCP6 port 
29/08/2024 13:40:11 Autoprobing selected TCP6 port 5900
29/08/2024 13:40:11 listen6: bind: Address already in use
29/08/2024 13:40:11 Not listening on IPv6 interface.
29/08/2024 13:40:11 
29/08/2024 13:40:11 Xinerama is present and active (e.g. multi-head).
29/08/2024 13:40:11 Xinerama: number of sub-screens: 2
29/08/2024 13:40:11 Xinerama: enabling -xwarppointer mode to try to correct
29/08/2024 13:40:11 Xinerama: mouse pointer motion. XTEST+XINERAMA bug.
29/08/2024 13:40:11 Xinerama: Use -noxwarppointer to force XTEST.
29/08/2024 13:40:11 Xinerama: sub-screen[0]  1366x768+0+0
29/08/2024 13:40:11 Xinerama: sub-screen[1]  1920x1080+1366+0
29/08/2024 13:40:11 blackout rect: 1366x312+0+768: x=0-1366 y=768-1080
29/08/2024 13:40:11 
29/08/2024 13:40:11 fb read rate: 1678 MB/sec
29/08/2024 13:40:11 The X server says there are 10 mouse buttons.
29/08/2024 13:40:11 screen setup finished.
29/08/2024 13:40:11 
29/08/2024 13:40:11 WARNING: You are running x11vnc WITHOUT a password.  See
29/08/2024 13:40:11 WARNING: the warning message printed above for more info.
29/08/2024 13:40:11 

Can guacamole be made to pan the necessary part of the virtual screens and apply the scaling to that portion only?
When I use krdc I'm able to scroll the windows to the necessary part of the screen and the screen is normalized.
When I use a laptop screen with 1920x1080 screen which matches the monitor, using the option -geometry 3840x1080+1920+0 the display works fine as expected.
